# Multiple patterns not working with if let

Tags: rust

You can use `if let` to pattern match on a range:

```
let n=1
if let 1...3 = n { println!("found in range") }
```

but I can't make it work on multiple patterns:

```
// this does not compile
if let 1 | 2 | 3 = n { println!("found in pattern") }
//      -^ unexpected token
```

I thought the second `if let` desugared to:

```
// this does compile and work
match n {
    1 | 2 | 3 => println!("found in pattern"),
    _ => {}
}
```

so what gives? Am I using the wrong syntax? Is my expectation that multiple patterns should work just misguided? Is this just not implemented?

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9fe3df3ff2357d0e5f4e32757dc28641&version=stable)

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/935

Comment: @interjay ah thanks, so it is just not implemented. The github issue does mention multiple patterns but then the discussion focuses on guards. For some reason (ugly resulting syntax?) I was less surprised that guards don't work with if let. Ranges working vs multiple patterns not working seems a bit less intuitive for me...

Comment: **NOTE**: `if let` now works on multiple patterns (tested as of Rust 1.61)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`if let` just doesn't support multiple patterns (see [RFC issue 935](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/935)).  Use `match` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this sort of thing you can also use the `matches!` macro (introduced in 2020):

```rust
if matches!(n, 1 | 2 | 3) {
    println!("found in range")
}
```

This also works in certian circumstances where you can't use `if let`, letting you write compound statements: `if b && matches!(n, 1 | 2 | 3)`

Comment: Quite strange to say that, since the `matches!()` macro was stabilized after or patterns in `if let`... (Rust 1.42.0 vs 1.33.0) ;)

Comment: I don't actually know that much about rust's development history.  I still think this is a better way to do this since it supports things like `if b && matches!(n, 1 | 2 | 3)` which as far as I can tell you still can't do with `if let` (as well as letting you just get a boolean for this sort of thing in other cases)

Comment: [`if let` chains](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2497-if-let-chains.html). I agree this is better if you can, this was just a joke.

Answer (score 0):

It works now ([since Rust 1.33.0](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1330-2019-02-28)), thanks to [RFC 2175, or-patterns in let and if / while let expressions](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2175-if-while-or-patterns.md).